# Simplest way to classify reducibility of principal series for $p$-adic $\mathrm{SL}_2$

Tags: rt.representation-theory, reductive-groups, p-adic-groups

Let $F$ be a $p$-adic field and $G_1=\mathrm{SL}_2(F)\subset \mathrm{GL}_2(F)=G$. For simplicity, we assume $p>2$. Denote by $|\cdot|$ the normalized absolute value on $F$. Here I shall focus on complex smooth representations.

The classification of irreducible smooth representations of $G_1$ is quite well-known (I wasn't sure whether Shalika's thesis is the first to classify them). It is similar to $\mathrm{GL}_2$, but there are crucial differences. One of the key point is the reducibility of the principal series.

So let $B_1=T_1N_1$ be the standard upper triangular Borel of $G_1$, $T_1$ the group of diagonals and $N_1$ the unipotent radical; similar for $G$: $B=TU$. If we write a character $\chi$ of $T$ in terms of
$$\chi=\chi_1\boxtimes \chi_2,$$
where $\chi_1,\chi_2$ are characters of $F^\times$, then the normalized parabolic induction
$$I_B^G(\chi)$$
is reducible if and only if $\chi_1\chi_2^{-1}=|\cdot|^{\pm 1}$.

For $B_1$, the reducibility is more interesting. For any character $\chi$ of $F^\times$, we identify it with a character of $T_1$ in the usual way:
$$\chi:\begin{bmatrix}t & \\
& t^{-1}\end{bmatrix}\mapsto \chi(t).$$
Then the reducibility of $I_{B_1}^{G_1}(\chi)$ includes not only the case $\chi=|\cdot|^{\pm 1}$ (parallel to $G$), but also
$$\chi=|\cdot|^{\pm 1}\cdot \eta$$
for all nontrivial quadartic characters $\eta:F^\times \rightarrow \{\pm 1\}$. This interesting phenomenon is closely related to the structure of L-packets and Langlands parameters for ${\rm SL}_2(F)$.

As expained in Tadić's nice lecture notes *Jacquet modules and induced representations*, Math. Commun.3(1998), no.1, 1–17, this reducibility can not be proved by merely studying Jacquet modules. I guess Tadić's paper *Notes on representations of non-Archimedean SL(n)*, Pacific J. Math.152(1992), no.2, 375–396, may contain some other useful related information.

But here I just want to ask: **is there an adhoc simple method to classify these reducibilities**? (For $\mathrm{GL}_2$, we can use either the Whittaker model/Kirillov model, or Jacquet module + Frobenius reciprocity.) I searched the literature, except for Shalika's thesis (which is not readable for me), it seems that there's no paper dealing with this. (Thanks a lot in advance!)

---

(p.s. A related question: as is well-known, Shalika's thesis used the Weil representation, or the local theta correspondence, to construct all the supercuspidals of $\mathrm{SL}_2(F)$. Is there a good paper which re-write the exhaustion result related to this construction?)